# Should I wrap all React render code with try{} catch(err){}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sometimes React fails silently when running `render` code. It's then hard to find out where it broke.

I wonder, if I should just put all the code for `render` function inside `try {} catch(err) {alert(err)}`?

Is it a good practice or should I catch and debug errors in a different way?

One of the cases it shows no errors is when I send some props variables to a component which are actually undefined and it tries to get properties of that undefined variable, like this:

```
<FormField form={this.props.form} />
```

Then, inside `FormField` component `render` function there is this code:

```
var value = this.props.form[this.props.id]
```

Now, if form prop is undefined, the code in FormField component doesn't show any error, but when I use try/catch, it shows this:

[image: Error caught with try/catch]

Probably I should use try/catch to debug the errors then fix and add checks, then remove try/catch for production?

Comment: Fails silently? React never fails silently, what React does is that it does not render falsey values. I've been using React for a while and so far I've never had the need to wrap render code within a try/catch, yet.

Comment: In any case, I can catch errors in my components, when I use `try/catch` but can't see some of them when I don't use it.

Comment: Can you give any examples of code that fails silently?

Comment: Please have a look at the update above

Comment: There is something else that's happening. I reproduced your components in a minimal example here: http://jsfiddle.net/apbujaxg/ and which you can clearly see, the console gives an error.

Comment: Can it be a result of using Promises somewhere else in the app?

Comment: Could be, impossible to know since you have posted very little code. Furthermore you should invest in using PropTypes in order to validate your props being passed.

Comment: How can using promises possibly be relevant?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could benefit from [prop validation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation). Then you can decide upon types for your props.

```
React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    form: React.PropTypes.object,
    id: React.PropTypes.string
  }
  // ...
})
```

Then if you don't supply a property of the correct type, it will log an error.

Alternatively, you could supply a [default value](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) for the property if that would be more appropriate.

```
React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      form: defaultFormProp
    };
  }
});
```

Then if you don't supply the prop when you render the component, the default value will be used.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question wether or not putting render in a try catch is a good idea though

Comment: I think you can safely infer a no from the answer. Wrapping calls to render in try catch is superflous when React already comes with a fine grained approach for catching errors related to props.

Comment: Not all errors are related to props. Right now, I'm dealing with React silently failing, no idea why. And while try/catch doesn't remotely look like a good solution, this answer doesn't help at all when all React gives back is silence :(